# Access Denied when read from Pre-signed URL generated from static website

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

I have a static website where on the UI I am taking bucketname, objectname from an HTML form hosted in an S3 bucket. After clicking a button, these parameters are then sent to an API gateway via POST which in turn forward it to Lambda. Lambda is then generating a presigned URL based on those parameters and sending it back to the UI. When I generate the URL from the Lambda it works but I get an Access denied when I try to access the object from the URL generated by the UI. Here is my bucket policy where the object is stored:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PresignedPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/accessS3"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::testEXAMPLEbucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My CORS config for the bucket where the object is stored.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Lambda Code:

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3()

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    var params = {
            'Bucket' : event['bucketName'],
            'Key' : event['objectName'],
            'Expires' : event['expiration']
    };

   s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, (error, url) => {
    if (error) {
      callback(error);
    } else {
      callback(null, {url: url});
    }
  });

};
```

HTML script code:

```
var API_ENDPOINT_POST = "https://***.**-api.us-east-1.**.com/prod/"

//AJAX POST REQUEST
document.getElementById("getURL").onclick = function(){
  var inputData = {
    "bucketName":$('#bucketName').val(),
        "objectName":$('#objectName').val(),
        "expiration":$('#expiration').val()         
      };
  $.ajax({
        url: API_ENDPOINT_POST,
        type: 'POST',
        data:  JSON.stringify(inputData)  ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
          document.getElementById("showURL").value = response.url;
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

The role used in Lambda has FULLS3ACCESS. I have read most of the posts and did changes according to them but none of them helped. Please do let me know if I am missing anything. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Unrelated: you should not allow the web code to specify the bucket and probably not the expiration, either.  These open you up to potential misuse of your Lambda function by malicious actors.  At minimum, the Lambda code needs to validate these parameters and refuse to sign the URL if they don't match expectations.

Comment: Pre-signed URL generation still works if the object key is incorrect or the object doesn't exist -- `s3.getSignedUrl()` does not actually interact with S3, it does the entire signature calculation in memory.  Consider temporarily changing the policy to allow `"Action": [ "s3:GetObject", "s3:ListBucket" ],
            "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::testEXAMPLEbucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::testEXAMPLEbucket/*"
            ]`.  This will enable a `NoSuchKey` error to be returned instead of `AccessDenied` if the object key is the problem, which is my initial speculation.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot:Thank you for your concern. All the names on here are fake :). I tried your suggestion but got an Access Denied in both cases whether I give a correct/incorrect bucket or object name.

Comment: I understand that the values are not real.  My concern is that your Lambda function *trusts the browser* to make a valid request, which is not good practice.  Code running in the browser is easily modified by a malicious user, and thus its behavior is not to be trusted.  So you changed the bucket policy and the result is the same, when using a valid bucket and valid object key?  If so, please take a signed URL you generated, and change any one digit in the `X-Amz-Signature` to a different digit, for example, change any `0` to `1`.  Verify that this results in a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes. Even if I give an incorrect bucket/object get the same error. I changed the Amz-signature and got the same Access Denied error. What does this mean? Appreciate your help.

Comment: That should be impossible.  Tweaking characters in the signature should not result in an `AccessDenied` error, because the presence of a signature should trigger the service to *first* validate the signature *before* testing privileges.  (To do otherwise would give an attacker potentially valuable information.)  Can you show one of these signed URLs that you're generating?

Comment: Here you go : https://testdiggybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test_file.docx?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIASON6IP722YPMUA6Q&Expires=1551486021&Signature=xUxOX42928Su4DSLzGRPGN3yvvc%3D&x-amz-security-token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEAoaDAG5GF82aE9%2BmVb3VSLoAa70i2sX3M1ZWB2SWlyta%2F1lwY8Tsp9sVk%2F3kEgKyZss%2Fl3S7bAh0MfE1TwVdBbi36GDghshbKLORlfpAIZrLIK8n7k7%2FJ%2BBaaUOBfJnrv%2F1d7XUhSbaxRUmPsAKwqUNc%2F%2FHABQ%2B%2BC3%2Bw4ZyT9%2BKvULdNro3e6g85hnWe%2FknSKturvGA02%2Fy%2F2PEs0X2JGxLKIqbvExRseIbcjJBjaKSyk2BJF4Jvw4QAiGaRMOTlghmDj9XPp8rlhChk1BBsbFjghii2miV8nGpa9x9l%2Bc2VBepdJfruFkSrdPKYQGAnCBtZqInXWVUjvwoxJjn4wU%3D

Comment: This URL has now expired, and I get an error to that effect. `<Code>AccessDenied</Code>`
`<Message>Request has expired</Message>`  This particular URL expired almost 4 hours ago, perhaps very close to the time you shared it. Please confirm that you *now* see the message about the request being expired, but that you did not see this previously.

Comment: No no. I saw this even before. Like the moment I clicked on the link it showed request expired. I even specified the expires attribute of the link as 4000 which I mean is 4000 secs, right?

Comment: You didn't mention that.  The link you provided uses Signature Version 2.  The `Expires` value in the URL is Unix epoch time -- the number of seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.  As I am typing this, any URL with a value less than 1551575460 is already expired.  If your clock is wrong or system time zone is wrong, the expiration of your URLs will be offset, too, and expire either before you signed them or more in the future than you intended.

Comment: Well I entered 9999999999 and I still get the Access denied : Request expired. Is the time not getting converted correctly?

Comment: Please generate a URL setting `Expires` to 3600 (that's 60 minutes).  Note the current time in UTC when you do this.  Test it immediately.  If it fails, capture the `<Expires>` and `<ServerTime>` elements from the error message and let us know what you see.

Comment: Ok so I did that. This is the response `<Expires>2019-03-08T01:12:20Z</Expires>`
`<ServerTime>2019-03-08T01:12:27Z</ServerTime>` When I clicked the button to get URL the time was `1:11 AM
Friday, March 8, 2019
Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)
Unix Time : 1551978660` --> Unix time might not be accurate
Here is the full response: `<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
<Expires>2019-03-08T01:12:20Z</Expires>
<ServerTime>2019-03-08T01:12:27Z</ServerTime>
<RequestId>27D0DC49BBC64F89</RequestId>
<HostId>
XX
</HostId>
</Error>`

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(params));` ... it sounds like `Expires` was not really set to 3600.  Perhaps it's a *string* and not a number... not sure how the SDK would handle that case, but it might be getting coerced to 0.

Comment: Here is the console log: `{ "Bucket": "testbucket", "Key": "testfile.txt", "Expires": "9999999999" }`  **Not actual bucket and file**

Comment: I don't think expires is the issue. Here is the link tested directly from lambda function that works : `https://testdiggybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test_file.docx?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIASON6IP725QW56KDF&Expires=1552325300` and here is the link generated from clicking the button on UI immediately after the test: `https://testdiggybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test_file.docx?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIASON6IP725QW56KDF&Expires=1552324302` the Expires field seems good I think. Is there some sort of permission config that I am missing when a UI is added?

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, the second URL in your comment expired 998 seconds earlier than the first one.  Doesn't that seem wrong to you?

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry I read the numbers wrong. So I tested this out and no matter what number I give, the expires parameter is set to current time. It works when I hardcode the expires parameter in the Lambda though.

Comment: There it is.  So they are instantly expired.  Try `'Expires' : Number(event['expiration'])`

Comment: OMG!! Can't believe this is where I screwed up. Thank you so much!! Could you please post your answer so that I can Mark and Upvote it. Thank you so much.